# Json Call can't interpret PHP variable in Jquery Mobile App

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to load event calendar from Database, I got this code on line and is working perfectly.

My javascript:

```
$('#mycalendar').monthly({
    mode: 'event',
    jsonUrl: 'http://localhost/acadasuite_mobile/www/calendar.php',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

**My PHP**

```
   $startdate = "2016-10-6";
   echo '{
    "monthly": [
       {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "This is a JSON event",
         "startdate": "2016-10-6",
         "enddate": "",
         "starttime": "12:00",
         "endtime": "2:00",
         "color": "#EF44EF",
         "url": ""
      }
    ]
  }';
```

ABOVE WORK WELL. But if I change the "2016-10-6" to '.$startdate.', it will not work again

ie. "startdate": '.$startdate.',

Please, what can be the problem; Is it the the javascript does not interpret the variable $startdate or PHP?

Comment: Read up on [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Never try and build a JSONString yourself

Comment: You should create that object as an associative array and then use `json_encode()` to format the response.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will not interpret variables inside strings denoted with single quotes. Switch to double quotes on the outside and escape your double quotes on the inside.

Alternatively, use string concatenation:

```
$startdate = "2016-10-6";
echo '{
"monthly": [
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "This is a JSON event",
     "startdate": "'.$stardate.'",
     "enddate": "",
     "starttime": "12:00",
     "endtime": "2:00",
     "color": "#EF44EF",
     "url": ""
  }
]
}';
```

Comment: **BUT** Read up on [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Never try and build a JSONString yourself

Answer (score 0):

You forgot quotes:

```
"startdate": "2016-10-6", etc...
```

becomes

```
"startdate": ' . $stardate . ', etc..
```

which generates

```
 "startdate":2016-10-6, etc...
```

which is **NOT** valid JSON. Json can only represent VALUES, not expressions. And even if expressions were supported, that'd be a mathematical subtraction, and you'd be putting the value `2000` into `startdate`.

You need quotes:

```
     "startdate": "' . $startdate . '",
                  ^------------------^
```

To show where the (j)son/(p)hp delineation is:

```
     "startdate": "' . $startdate . '",
     jjjjjjjjjjjjjjppppppppppppppppppjj
```